# Creating a common interface

Tags: c

I have a sort of database with a [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) association between tags and files. For various reasons, I decided to forgo a junction table in favor of having the left and right tables store the associated values in the tables themselves. However I've ended up writing code like this:

```
GHashTable *tagdb_get_tag_files (tagdb *db, int tag_code)
{
    return g_hash_table_lookup(db->reverse, GINT_TO_POINTER(tag_code));
}

GHashTable *tagdb_get_file_tags (tagdb *db, int file_id)
{
    return g_hash_table_lookup(db->forward, GINT_TO_POINTER(file_id));
}

void tagdb_remove_tag (tagdb *db, int id)
{
    GHashTable *its_files = g_hash_table_lookup(db->reverse, GINT_TO_POINTER(id));
    if (its_files == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    GHashTableIter it;
    gpointer key, value;
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&it, its_files);
    if (g_hash_table_iter_next(&it, &key, &value))
    {
        tagdb_remove_tag_from_file(db, id, key);
    }
    g_hash_table_remove(db->reverse, GINT_TO_POINTER(id));
}

void tagdb_remove_file(tagdb *db, int id)
{
    GHashTable *its_tags = g_hash_table_lookup(db->forward, GINT_TO_POINTER(id));
    if (its_tags == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    GHashTableIter it;
    gpointer key, value;
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&it, its_tags);
    if (g_hash_table_iter_next(&it, &key, &value))
    {
        tagdb_remove_file_from_tag(db, id, key);
    }
    g_hash_table_remove(db->forward, GINT_TO_POINTER(id));
}
```

Where only a few identifiers change, but basically the same thing happens, just on different sides. Is there a simpler, less error prone way to do this in c? Maybe with macros?

Comment: What are the types of `db->forward` and `db->reverse`

Comment: both are `HashTable*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I've done is to index the tables numerically while passing in the index to each function that accesses a particular table. The setup isn't much different to Loki's, but additionally allows me to work with my notion of parity by checking the passed in table id.

```
GHashTable *tagdb_get_sub (tagdb *db, int item_id, int sub_id, int table_id)
{
    GHashTable *sub_table = tagdb_get_item(db, item_id, table_id);
    return g_hash_table_lookup(sub_table, GINT_TO_POINTER(sub_id));
}

void tagdb_remove_sub (tagdb *db, int item_id, int sub_id, int table_id)
{
    GHashTable *sub_table = tagdb_get_item(db, item_id, table_id);
    if (sub_table != NULL)
    {
        g_hash_table_remove(sub_table, GINT_TO_POINTER(item_id));
    }
}

void tagdb_remove_item (tagdb *db, int item_id, int table_id)
{
    GHashTable *its_associates = tagdb_get_item(db, item_id, table_id);
    if (its_associates == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    GHashTableIter it;
    gpointer key, value;
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&it, its_associates);
    int other = (table_id == FILE_TABLE)?TAG_TABLE:FILE_TABLE;
    if (g_hash_table_iter_next(&it, &key, &value))
    {
        printf("removing %d from %s\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(key), (other == FILE_TABLE)?"File table":"Tag table");
        tagdb_remove_sub(db, item_id, GPOINTER_TO_INT(key), other);
    }
    g_hash_table_remove(db->tables[table_id], GINT_TO_POINTER(item_id));
}

GHashTable *tagdb_get_item (tagdb *db, int item_id, int table_id)
{
    return g_hash_table_lookup(db->tables[table_id], GINT_TO_POINTER(item_id));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function that gets the correct object from tagdb.
AKA Service Locator pattern

```
typedef HashTable* (*ITEM_GETTER)(tagdb*);

HashTable* getTag(tagdb *db)  { return db->reverse;}
HashTable* getFile(tagdb *db) { return db->forward;}

GHashTable *tagdb_get_item_files (tagdb *db, int itemId, ITEM_GETTER getter)
{
    return g_hash_table_lookup(getter(db), GINT_TO_POINTER(itemId));
}

void tagdb_remove_item (tagdb *db, int id, ITEM_GETTER getter)
{
    GHashTable *its_files = g_hash_table_lookup(getter(db), GINT_TO_POINTER(id));
    if (its_files == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    GHashTableIter it;
    gpointer key, value;
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&it, its_files);
    if (g_hash_table_iter_next(&it, &key, &value))
    {
        tagdb_remove_tag_from_file(db, id, key);
    }
    g_hash_table_remove(getter(db), GINT_TO_POINTER(id));
}
```

#### Edit for clarity:

The old functions can now be implanted like this:

```
GHashTable *tagdb_get_tag_files (tagdb *db, int tag_code)
{
    return tagdb_get_item_files(db, tag_code, getTag);
}

GHashTable *tagdb_get_file_tags (tagdb *db, int file_id)
{
    return return tagdb_get_item_files(db, file_id, getFile);
}

void tagdb_remove_tag (tagdb *db, int id)
{
    tagdb_remove_item(db, id, getTag);
}

void tagdb_remove_file(tagdb *db, int id)
{
    tagdb_remove_item(db, id, getFile);
}
```

Comment: I think I like this. I'm not sure about the tagdb_remove_tag_from_file since it removes from an item in the opposite table.